# Merge [fb-hydra] and [hydra-python]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[fb-hydra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fb-hydra) and [hydra-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hydra-python) appear to be about the same framework and should be merged.